# How to clean service state before a test?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm writing tests for a simple, mongoose-based service:

```
describe('users service', () => {
    const service = app.service('users');

    it('registered the service', () => {
        assert.ok(service, 'Registered the service');
    });
});
```

The problem is, how do I clean the data before each test?

Right now I have:

```
// Reset service state before each test.
beforeEach((done) => {
    service.find().then((items) => {
        items.data.forEach((item) => {
            service.remove(item._id)
        });

        done();
    })
});
```

This is awkward. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest adapter version you can also temporarily set the `multi` option to allow removing all entries and call `.remove(null)`:

```
// Reset service state before each test.
beforeEach(async () => {
  const multi = service.options.multi;
  service.options.multi = 'remove';

  await service.remove(null);

  service.options.multi = multi;
});
```

This will also wait until everything is removed (which your example wouldn't do).